# 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' in aws ec2 windows server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, bitnami

Hi trying to host a Laravel 5.4 php web site in aws ec2 windows server-(http://3.133.59.5/) and also using bitnami-7.3 run Laravel project.I'm getting following error when run the error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
```

i tried change the ***config/database.php*** and add

```
            'modes'  => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ],
```

but it didn't fix the this issue

Comment: `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` is obsolete and [was removed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html) from MySQL Server 8.0, which is the version in bitnami-7.3.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. The Bitnami WAMP 7.3 solutions includes MySQL 8.x so as @Michael-sqlbot mentioned, that mode is not supported anymore. Thanks